# React DOM create html element and bind function to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
return React.DOM.div({className:"dragHandlerWrap"}, React.DOM.div({
    className: "dragHandler left"
}, "< left")
```

Above code will render as

```
<div class="dragHandlerWrap">
  <div class="dragHandler left">< left</div>
</div>
```

How can I add a function on it? like if jsx you can simply bind a function using onClick, but how about in above case?

Comment: If you have the jsx version in handy try using https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX is basically just syntactic sugar for a function call.

```
<div onClick={handler} />
```

becomes

```
React.createElement('div', {onClick: handler});
```

All props are become properties of a single object.

Hence in your example it will be something like

```
React.DOM.div({
  className: "dragHandler left",
  onClick: handler,
}, "< left")
```

Comment: make lot of senes, can I do setState directly to it instead of assigning it to a handler function?

Comment: tried `onClick: () => (this.setState({something:true})` doesn't work, got syntax error.

Comment: `onClick: () => (this.setState({something:true})` is certainly not invalid syntax (if inside an object literal). But whether it works depends on the context. Whose component's state are you trying to change?